# Add HTML Table data into MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML table and a button that allows the user to add multiple rows.

```
<table id="component_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Component Type</th>
            <th>Component Thickness</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="component_tb">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $roofComponentDropDown ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $roofComponentTypeDropDown ?></td> 
            <td><input id="component_thickness" name="component_thickness" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" />
```

These are my drop downs that are being generated for the table

```
//Queries here to get data for the drop down lists that make up the roof construction table...
$roofComponentQuery = "SELECT * FROM roof_component";
$roofComponentData = mysqli_query($dbc, $roofComponentQuery);

while ($rcRow = mysqli_fetch_array($roofComponentData)) {
         $roofComponentOptions .="<option value=\"".$rcRow['roof_component_id']."\">" . $rcRow['roof_component_name'] . "</option>";
}

$roofComponentDropDown = "<select name='selectedRoofComponent' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this)'>
                            <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Component</option>
                        " . $roofComponentOptions . "
                        </select></br>";

$roofComponentTypeDropDown = "<select name='selectedComponentType' id='selectedComponentType'>
                                <option class='toggle_control' selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Type</option>
                            </select></br>";
```

Is there a way to add each `<tr>` into an array, then iterate through the array with a foreach loop and insert each `<tr>` into the DB?

Something like this maybe?

```
$tableRow = array(); 
foreach ($tableRow as $row) {
    //insert query
}
```

Comment: Do you have a form to submit the table to PHP?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the table is in a form with several other input fields.

Comment: You'll have to give, more information, the mysql table schema and  the complete PHP code

Comment: @perodriguezl you don't need my table schema to answer the question, and I believe I have added in enough PHP here to support my question.

Comment: ok, good luck with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<select>` elements names ending in `[]`.

```
$roofComponentDropDown = "<select name='selectedRoofComponent[]' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this)'>
                            <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Component</option>
                        " . $roofComponentOptions . "
                        </select></br>";
$roofComponentTypeDropDown = "<select name='selectedComponentType[]' id='selectedComponentType'>
                                <option class='toggle_control' selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Type</option>
                            </select></br>";
```

Then the elements of `$_POST` will be arrays that you can loop over.

```
foreach ($_POST['selectedRoofComponent'] as $index => $component) {
    $componentType = $_POST['selectedComponentType'][$index];
    // INSERT $component and $componentType into database
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but will not give the OP the structure which he asked about, which is a single array of `$tableRow` he can iterate over.  Furthermore there's a bit of a leap of faith necessary in regards to which row each element's index belongs in.  If something goes awry client side while generating new rows, he will end up with data in the wrong places.

Comment: He said "something like this", I think my answer is something like it. It doesn't have to be a single array, just something he can iterate over.

Comment: @Barmar Bonus Points(avoiding asking another question): I have implemented your answer and it seems to be working how it should. However I am trying to add `[]` to my `component_thickness` input field and I have done `$componentThickness = $_POST['component_thickness'][$index];` but I am only getting the last value I have entered in.

Comment: Are you changing the values of these fields dynamically with Javascript? You could be running into problems because they all have the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure each `<tr>` and subsequently newly created `<tr>` has a unique row id.  Then use this to create the array index assign names to your elements in each `<td>` which are submitted with the form.

Perhaps something like `<select name='tableRow[rowId][selectedRoofComponent]' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this)'>` this should give you an array with the appropriate structure in your POST data.

`rowId` in this case needs to be a variable which is either generated by your javascript or rendered by php when the page loads. So in php it might look something like:

```
"<select name='tableRow[" . $rowId . "][selectedRoofComponent]' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this)'>"
```

or if javascript

```
"<select name='tableRow[" + rowId + "][selectedRoofComponent]' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this)'>"
```

To give you anything more specific than this I'd need to see the javascript as well.